# hhERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint: MULTI VALUED REFERENCED TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, erd

Using InnoDB = Yes
Spelling = used the relationship referencing of workbench(more or less should be correct)
Primary key = Yes

I dont really know how to solve this one...I wanted PEO-MVAlign's SCHOOLID to be referenced to MVALIGN and PEO's SchoolID...but one only one SCHOOL ID should be seen or exist in the PEO-MVALIGN table..

**Error Message**

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PEO-MVAlign` (
          `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
          `values` CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
          `DegreeProgram` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `PEOCode` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `values`, `DegreeProgram`, `PEOCode`),
          INDEX `fk_PEO-MVAlign_MVAlign1_idx` (`SchoolID` ASC, `values` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_PEO-MVAlign_PEO1_idx` (`SchoolID` ASC, `DegreeProgram` ASC, `PEOCode` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_PEO-MVAlign_MVAlign1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID` , `values`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`MVAlign` (`SchoolID` , `values`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_PEO-MVAlign_PEO1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`DegreeProgram` , `PEOCode` , `SchoolID`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`PEO` (`DegreeProgram` , `PEOCode` , `SchoolID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 23 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

**Codes**

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`REF-School`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-School` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-School` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `SchoolName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`MVAlign`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`MVAlign` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`MVAlign` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `values` CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `values`),
  INDEX `fk_MVAlign_REF-School` (`SchoolID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_MVAlign_REF-School`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`REF-School` (`SchoolID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`REF-Degree`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-Degree` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-Degree` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `DegreeProgram` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `DegreeProgram`),
  INDEX `fk_REF-Degree_REF-School1` (`SchoolID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_REF-Degree_REF-School1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`REF-School` (`SchoolID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`REF-Courses`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-Courses` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-Courses` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `DegreeProgram` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `CourseCode` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `Unit` DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL,
  `CourseDescription` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `DegreeProgram`, `CourseCode`),
  INDEX `FK_COURSEStoDEGREE` (`SchoolID` ASC, `DegreeProgram` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_COURSEStoDegree`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID` , `DegreeProgram`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`REF-Degree` (`SchoolID` , `DegreeProgram`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`REF-Courses`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-Courses` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`REF-Courses` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `DegreeProgram` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `CourseCode` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `Unit` DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL,
  `CourseDescription` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `DegreeProgram`, `CourseCode`),
  INDEX `FK_COURSEStoDEGREE` (`SchoolID` ASC, `DegreeProgram` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_COURSEStoDegree`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID` , `DegreeProgram`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`REF-Degree` (`SchoolID` , `DegreeProgram`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`IGOA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`IGOA` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`IGOA` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `IGOCode` CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `IGA` CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `GradOutcome` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `IGOCode`),
  INDEX `FK_IGOAtoSchool` (`SchoolID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_IGOAtoSchool`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`REF-School` (`SchoolID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`IGO-MVAlign`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`IGO-MVAlign` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`IGO-MVAlign` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `values` CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `IGOCode` CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `values`, `IGOCode`),
  INDEX `fk_IGO-MVAlign_IGOA1_idx` (`SchoolID` ASC, `IGOCode` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_IGO-MVAlign_MVAlign1_idx` (`SchoolID` ASC, `values` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IGO-MVAlign_IGOA1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID` , `IGOCode`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`IGOA` (`SchoolID` , `IGOCode`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IGO-MVAlign_MVAlign1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID` , `values`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MVAlign` (`SchoolID` , `values`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PEO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`PEO` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PEO` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `DegreeProgram` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `PEOCode` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  `EducObj` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `DegreeProgram`, `PEOCode`),
  INDEX `FK_PEOtoREF-DEGREE` (`SchoolID` ASC, `DegreeProgram` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PEOtoREF-DEGREE`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID` , `DegreeProgram`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`REF-Degree` (`SchoolID` , `DegreeProgram`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PEO-MVAlign`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`PEO-MVAlign` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PEO-MVAlign` (
  `SchoolID` DECIMAL(5) NOT NULL,
  `values` CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `DegreeProgram` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `PEOCode` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolID`, `values`, `DegreeProgram`, `PEOCode`),
  INDEX `fk_PEO-MVAlign_MVAlign1_idx` (`SchoolID` ASC, `values` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_PEO-MVAlign_PEO1_idx` (`SchoolID` ASC, `DegreeProgram` ASC, `PEOCode` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PEO-MVAlign_MVAlign1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SchoolID` , `values`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MVAlign` (`SchoolID` , `values`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PEO-MVAlign_PEO1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DegreeProgram` , `PEOCode` , `SchoolID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PEO` (`DegreeProgram` , `PEOCode` , `SchoolID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What did you find when you searched for "mysql error 1215"?

Answer (score 0):

An SQL [FOREIGN KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) in one table REFERENCES a corresponding column list in another table. The column correspondence between the FK and the referenced table is not by name but by order of column in the lists.

The referenced column list must be declared UNIQUE NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY in the referenced table. The types of corresponding columns must have certain agreement (including integer to integer and string to string). Also in MySQL the FK columns must have an index with the columns as its first columns in the same order. Under MySQL with InnoDB the referenced columns must have an index in their table with the columns as its first columns in the same order. (Some indexes can be implicit, eg for PRIMARY KEY or FOREIGN KEY.)

For the PEO-MVAlign PEO FK the referenced columns are not in the same order as the referencing columns. This pairs up differently named columns in PEO-MVAlign and PEO. Which is probably not you want; probably you want the referencing and referenced column lists to  be in the same order. But (none of) the types of corresponding columns match, so the correspondence is not allowed. But even if they were allowed, the referenced column list doesn't have the same names in the same order as an index in PEO-MVAlign or in PEO.